# How to reset Spotlight cache/index?

Tags: macos, spotlight

I uninstalled Parallels Desktop, so I don't have a Windows VM any more. However when I type `we` into Spotlight, the Windows Weather app comes first, and if I press it, it says Parallels Desktop is not installed anymore.

How do I clean the cache or re-build the index?  (I am not sure what this operation is called)?

**NOTE**: I would like to avoid having to use `sudo`.

Comment: Already checked $HOME/Library/Parallels/Application Menus/  and $HOME/Applications (Parallels)/ for links to (now deleted) Win apps?

Comment: This was the issue. I tried looking for a complete guide on how to uninstall completely parallel but couldn't find one that goes after the "drag n drop Parallels from Application to the Trash"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually it's not necessary to rebuild the Spotlight database to get rid of Windows applications of a deleted Windows VM in the Spotlight results.

To properly remove all traces of a deleted Windows VM with some kind of integration in macOS - like a VM specific Application menu - remove the links of the Windows apps in $HOME/Library/Parallels/Application Menus/ and/or $HOME/Applications (Parallels)/.

To remove Parallels Desktop completely from your Mac remove the following files and folders besides the main app in /Applications:

- $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.parallels.*
- $HOME/Library/Parallels
- $HOME/Applications (Parallels)/
- $HOME/Documents/Virtual Machines (or something similar - please check that it doesn't contain VMs of other type2 hypervisors like VMware)
- /usr/local/bin/prl* (possible soft links to Parallels command line tools in the app bundle)

Answer (score 5):

To see where an item in Spotlight is located, press ⌘↩︎ (cmd-return) to reveal the item in Finder. That error isn't something I'd expect if the item had actually been removed.

You can reindex your disk by adding the disk to System Preferences → Spotlight → Privacy (which will delete the index), then removing it from the list.

- https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201716